# How can I align these two tables / divs with a common parent header div?

Tags: html, css

This webapge I'm working on looks like this:

[image]

The HTML is loosely like this:

```
<div class="title">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td width="35%">Table 1a Header</td>
            <td width="65%">Table 2a Header</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="padding-all">
    <div class="body" style="width: 100%">
        <div><table> <!-- table 1b... --></div>
        <div><table> <!-- empty table for spacing --></div>
        <div><table> <!-- table 2b... --></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to achieve is either:

1) Have the text in my `<div class="title">` at the top align above the tables inside of my `<div class="body">`

**OR**

2) Have the "top" rows inside of the tables span the entire width of the page, so that there is no black whitespace, in essence making it appear similar to how the current title div appears.

Either way, I need the text for "1a" to align with "1b" and the same for 2a/2b. As well as have it with a gray background that spans the width of the page.

I'm much more of a developer than I am a designer and I cannot seem to figure out how I can get this to work. I've fudged around with the percentages for the title div's table data cells, but this only works on certain resolutions, otherwise it doesn't display correctly. What else can I do?

Comment: Have you tried embedding your "b" tables within your "a" table? You could use "empty" columns for spacing, thus aligning your headers. If you can, provide some CSS or a fiddle for others (and myself) to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish as a whole, one option is to embed your tables.

See my example in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jritchey/wxrheg4p/) where I've used the following code:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="2%"></th>
      <th width="33%">Table 1a Header</th>
      <th width="2%"></th>
      <th width="63%">Table 2a Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr height="10px">
      <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="2%"></td>
      <th width="33%">Table1b Header</th>
      <td width="2%"></td>
      <th width="63%">Table2b Header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="2%"></td>
      <td width="33%">
        <table><!-- Content --></table>
      </td>
      <td width="2%"></td>
      <td width="63%">
        <table><!-- Content --></table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```